# Specific meaning of 'ivory'

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

"The old-fashioned officers whom they encountered appeared to be '*ivory from the neck up*'."

From the sources I have searched, the word ivory does not appear to have any specific or metaphorical value. Thus how should I understand the expression in italics?

Comment: *This is in italics* - "This is in quotes, or between quotation marks" - 'this is between *single* quotation marks'

Comment: I intended the expression to be both in italics and between single quotation marks. For some unknown reason, the software missed the italics after I published the post — I did not.

Comment: Gotcha...at any rate the comment was only intended to be helpful, and it may still be helpful to someone else, so I'm inclined to leave it.

Comment: Which sources did you search? It's always a good idea to include those while you are asking the question. (ELU has one user who is particularly good at this, and his questions are often rightly rewarded. [Here's an example](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193855/what-does-bupke-mean), if you're interested, and you can find plenty more [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi?tab=questions&sort=votes), too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That word carries a lot of metaphorical meaning. In that case I believe that the word could be replaced with *stone*, meaning that the officers exhibited no facial expression. I'd have to see more context to be absolutely sure of the author's intent.

Just as points of interest concerning that word:

*Ivory* is also often used as a term for *white*, particularly the white race. A very well known song uses that metaphor, [Ebony and Ivory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmALA8miQY8)

Also, playing piano can be referred to as [tickling the ivories](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tickle%20the%20ivories)

Comment: It might also be a hint of all of them being white-haired from age, in addition to being with a fixed facial expression and of the white race.

Comment: @Peteris — That equates to rather different features. It may account for the fact the original citation displays the single quotation marks — meaning perhaps 'decide for yourself'…

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't heard this expression before - but Google Books claims "about 164 results" for ["ivory from the neck up"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20future%20please%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22ivory%20from%20the%20neck%20up%22&tbm=bks), and glancing through a few of them it seems the intended meaning is invariably ***[very] stupid***.

> [*But the local commander was **the most complete nit-wit**, solid ivory from the neck up.*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VKwvAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ivory%20from%20the%20neck%20up%22&dq=%22ivory%20from%20the%20neck%20up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NgEGVKvQOYmp0AWs2IGADQ&redir_esc=y)

My guess is the usage is at least partly based on the fact that *ivory* is very ***dense*** (*heavy, solid,* but also used figuratively to mean *thick, stupid*). It's over a century old, but gained currency during WW1 (it's most commonly used in respect of authority figures - particularly military ones).

Comment: A very interesting comment, indeed, though not entirely convincing. Could it not mean 'mentally rigid' instead?

Comment: @Brice C.: It could indeed. In practice, mental "rigidity" and "slowness" would usually amount to much the same thing when criticising an army officer's inability to react intelligently/creatively to some novel problem. But metaphorically, Victorian military colonials probably thought more in terms of ivory being *heavy, dense* rather than *rigid, hard* (since they would have constantly been dragging huge tusks around the country).